# Using "valign-wrapper" & "right-align" together

Tags: materialize

Materialize-CSS: Can valign-wrapper & right-align be used together in a single h5 tag ?
What I have observed untill now is, When they are used together, the text inside h5 is vertically aligned but not aligning to the right.

I want my text be both vertical & right aligned.

Please let me know if you know how to achieve this.

TIA
Jagan

Comment: i have explained many solution for this. i hope you understand..

Answer (score 0):

valign wrapper use display flex. So just add justify-content: flex-end; to align right in your div class in which you are using v-align.
Here is the code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4bbz813z/)

There are many other approaches to do this. One of them is, use valign wrapper for verticle center and make them relative and h5 as absolute and right:0 to make it right align. Here is the jsfiddle [code](https://jsfiddle.net/rhrrd57j/)

another one is,you can use make parent div as display:table and h5 as display:table-cell. Below is the snippet:-

```css
.heading{


display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:300px; width:300px;background:red;display:table">
<h5 class="heading">Hi this is testing</h5>
</div>
```

Comment: why row-reverse when you have `justify-content: flex-end;` ?

Comment: @IsmailFarooq ya we can use that also, but can also set direction, both will work

Comment: i guess justify-content: flex-end; is more flexible for just to make right align row-reverse will change the position as well if the parent has multiple child's

Comment: @IsmailFarooq yes you are right.  justify-content: flex-end; is the more accurate way. thanks for information

Answer (score 0):

Use [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.parent {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background: red;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <h5 class="child">Hi this is testing</h5>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `justify-content` to `.child` too:

```
.child {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when using the valign-wrapper for a tag it makes that element:

```
.valign-wrapper{
display:flex; 
align-items:center;
}
```

you can add the following is your css to make it center aligned:

```
.valign-wrapper{
justify-content:flex-end;
}
```